# Redux get/set action.payload.id from another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have Slice where I have maincheckbox. When I click him i check all other checkbox, and push their item.id from rest-api to array. For work with them in future.

```
const checkboxAdversSlice = createSlice({
    name: "checkbox",
    initialState: {
        mainCheckbox: false,
        subCheckboxes: [],
        allCheckboxes: false
    },
    reducers: {
        toggleMainCheckbox(state, action) {
            if (action.payload === true) {
                if (state.allCheckboxes === false) {
                    state.subCheckboxes.push(action.payload.id);
                }

                state.mainCheckbox = true;
                state.allCheckboxes = true;

            }
            else {
                state.mainCheckbox = false;
                state.allCheckboxes = false;
            }
            return state;
        },
    }
});

export default checkboxAdversSlice;
```

Check/uncheck to maincheckbox by event.target.checked.

```
 const getCheckboxesState = useSelector((state) => state.checkboxes)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleMainCheckboxChange = (event) => {
        dispatch(checkboxAction.toggleMainCheckbox(event.target.checked))
        console.log(getCheckboxesState)
    }

            <label className="container_checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" className="advers__settings advers__settings_checkbox"
                       onChange={handleMainCheckboxChange}
                />
                <span className="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
```

But I need to get all item.id from others checkbockes and push to arrays. When I click main chekbox.

```
<label className="container_checkbox">
                            <input key={item.id} type="checkbox" className="advers__settings advers__settings_checkbox"
                                  onChange={(e) => dispatch(checkboxAction.toggleMainCheckbox(item.id))} />
                            <span className="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
```

Comment: @phry I need to get all item.id from others checkbockes and push to array. When I click main chekbox.

Comment: The [Redux docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state) say, in any given case reducer, **Immer expects that you will either mutate the existing state, or construct a new state value yourself and return it, but not both in the same function!** Your `toggleMainCheckbox` reducer is doing both. Why are the two `onChange` callbacks sending different data types (`event.target.checked`: boolean and `item.id`: string | number) to the same reducer? Where are the child `input`s that react to the parent (main) `input`? Can you post more code in your question?

Comment: @kofeigen Last checkbox is subcheckbox maped from api. I just want check all subcheckboxes when mainCheckbox is true and set their item.id to array...

Comment: @Александр In case you haven't found a solution yet, a [demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-75864043) and [code repository](https://git.sr.ht/~kofeigen/parent-child-checkboxes) are available to give you inspiration. In the code, the checkboxes are controlled. `event.target.checked` is never used. Checkbox state is managed in the Redux store. The selected items (with their IDs) are available in the store at `state.checkbox.selected`. If this answers your question, I will update my Stack Overflow answer with the relevant code. Let me know if you have any questions.